# Azure ADF access Postgres server

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-postgresql, azure-adf

I have Azure ADF and Postgres server, and I want to connect ADF to postgress.

Currently I am generating token to connect to Postgres server. And I'm using the same token to connect using ADF. The problem with the token is, it expires in 1 hour and so not the best solution for Production environment.

My other options is to use a **local user** with username and password, however that's a security risk so I don't want to approach that option yet.

Is there a way I can configure Managed Identity between ADF and postgres so I don't need to generate token every 1 hour?

Answer (score 0):

The access token has a unified lifetime in a tenant.

User uses User access token while managed identity uses Application access token.

So even if you use a managed identity, you will also need to use an access token with a one-hour lifetime.

You can consider [configuring the lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) of the access token to the time you want.

The [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes) for your reference.

If you insist on using managed identity to solve this problem, you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-connect-with-managed-identity), just replace the managed identity of the VM with the managed identity of ADF.